# Android - How to color whole area of an image on user's tap and center it on the sceen?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-imageview, flood-fill

I'm working on a little project where the user can color whole areas of an white image by tapping on the touch-screen.

This is an example of image:

[image]

And this is not difficult, infact I use the flood fill algorithm to color the same-color areas separated by the black lines.
My problem is to center the image which I modify, in the screen.

I use the following code:

JAVA:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class Main extends Activity {

private RelativeLayout dashBoard;
private MyView myView;
public ImageView image;

Button b_red, b_blue, b_green, b_orange, b_clear;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    myView = new MyView(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    findViewById(R.id.dashBoard);
    findViewById(R.id.myImage);


    b_red = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_red);
    b_blue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_blue);
    b_green = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_green);
    b_orange = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_orange);

    b_red.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myView.changePaintColor(0xFFFF0000);
        }
    });

    b_blue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myView.changePaintColor(0xFF0000FF);
        }
    });

    b_green.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myView.changePaintColor(0xFF00FF00);
        }
    });

    b_orange.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myView.changePaintColor(0xFFFF9900);
        }
    });

    dashBoard = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.dashBoard);
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImage);
    dashBoard.addView(myView);
}

public class MyView extends View {

    private Paint paint;
    private Path path;
    public Bitmap mBitmap;
    public ProgressDialog pd;
    final Point p1 = new Point();
    public Canvas canvas;

    //Bitmap mutableBitmap ;
    public MyView(Context context) {

        super(context);

        this.paint = new Paint();
        this.paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
        this.paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5f);
        mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.forme).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        this.path = new Path();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
        this.paint.setColor(Color.RED);

        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                p1.x = (int) x;
                p1.y = (int) y;
                final int sourceColor = mBitmap.getPixel((int) x, (int) y);
                final int targetColor = paint.getColor();
                new TheTask(mBitmap, p1, sourceColor, targetColor).execute();
                invalidate();
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void clear() {
        path.reset();
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getCurrentPaintColor() {
        return paint.getColor();
    }

    public void changePaintColor(int color){
        this.paint.setColor(color);
    }

    class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

        Bitmap bmp;
        Point pt;
        int replacementColor, targetColor;

        public TheTask(Bitmap bm, Point p, int sc, int tc) {
            this.bmp = bm;
            this.pt = p;
            this.replacementColor = tc;
            this.targetColor = sc;
            pd.setMessage("Filling....");
            pd.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pd.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            FloodFill f = new FloodFill();
            f.floodFill(bmp, pt, targetColor, replacementColor);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            pd.dismiss();
            invalidate();
        }
    }
}

// Flood fill
public class FloodFill {

    public void floodFill(Bitmap image, Point node, int targetColor, int replacementColor) {

        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();
        int target = targetColor;
        int replacement = replacementColor;

        if (target != replacement) {
            Queue<Point> queue = new LinkedList<Point>();
            do {

                int x = node.x;
                int y = node.y;
                while (x > 0 && image.getPixel(x - 1, y) == target) {
                    x--;
                }

                boolean spanUp = false;
                boolean spanDown = false;
                while (x < width && image.getPixel(x, y) == target) {
                    image.setPixel(x, y, replacement);
                    if (!spanUp && y > 0 && image.getPixel(x, y - 1) == target) {
                        queue.add(new Point(x, y - 1));
                        spanUp = true;
                    } else if (spanUp && y > 0 && image.getPixel(x, y - 1) != target) {
                        spanUp = false;
                    }
                    if (!spanDown && y < height - 1 && image.getPixel(x, y + 1) == target) {
                        queue.add(new Point(x, y + 1));
                        spanDown = true;
                    } else if (spanDown && y < (height - 1) && image.getPixel(x, y + 1) != target) {
                        spanDown = false;
                    }
                    x++;
                }

            } while ((node = queue.poll()) != null);
        }
    }
}
}
```

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawingLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#969696"
tools:context=".Main" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/dashBoard"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/b_red"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="#DDDDDD" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b_red"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="#FF0000" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b_green"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b_red"
    android:background="#00FF00" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b_blue"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b_green"
    android:background="#0000FF" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b_orange"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b_blue"
    android:background="#FF9900" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Clear" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I run the project I get:

[image]

As you can see the image isn't extended in all the light-grey area! I suppose this problem is cause by the intercation with a general View added to the RelativeLayout which contains the ImageView.

Can you tell how can I exetend the image to all the light-grey area? And how can I intercact with the **ImageVie** component without using the **RelativeLayout** component?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is the size of your image? Can't `layout_width="fill_parent"` and `layout_height="fill_parent"` on your ImageView help in this case?

Comment: But I don't load the image in the ImageView, I don't know how to do it... I modify the image loaded from the memory and then I set it on the RelativeLayout.. 
I asked the question because I don't know how to set the image on the ImageView, and not on the Layout as I do now!
Anyway, I tried your suggestion and it doesn't work, uluckly!

Comment: i remains the same even if I set the layout's bounds "fill_parent"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**:

To get the size of your `MyView`, just override the onMeasure() method like this:

```
@Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

             w = widthMeasureSpec - MeasureSpec.EXACTLY;
             h = heightMeasureSpec - MeasureSpec.EXACTLY;

            Log.d("Dim", Integer.toString(w) + " | " + Integer.toString(h));
        }
```

---

Alright, I have found something which I think might be helpful to you. The reason that your Bitmap doesn't fill the canvas is because, obviously, it's small. Normally `Canvas.drawBitmap()` will take up the space as big as the image. Thereby, in order to fill up your screen with the Bitmap you should scale it before you draw it.

I did something very quick like this:

```
mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                       R.drawable.forme).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
this.path = new Path();

// Get the screen dimension
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
h = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
w = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBitmap, w, h, false);
```

And then in `onDraw()` you draw the scaled Bitmap instead:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0, paint);
```

Also make sure that you send the `scaledBitmap` to your `AsyncTask`:

```
...
final int sourceColor = scaledBitmap.getPixel((int) x, (int) y); //<- HERE
...
new TheTask(scaledBitmap, p1, sourceColor, targetColor).execute(); //<- AND HERE
```

**IMPORTANT**:

Here I get the screen dimensions to scale the bitmap. But it's not good as you can see below. Your canvas should only take up `dashBoard` space not the entire screen. So I recommend you to find the `dashBoard` dimension instead and scale the Bitmap accordingly.

[image: PaintTest]

Comment: Amazing! I'll try and I'll say you!!! Anyway this is what I was looking for!!! Thank you very much to you all for your help!!!

Comment: It works!!! Thank you @Sam Rad!

PS: Do you know how can I get the dimensions in pixels of the `dashBoard`?

Comment: @TheGreatGatsby, I think if you get the dimension of your `MyView` it would be enough. See the updated answer.

Comment: Ok I overrided the method, but I don't know where to call it and which parameters to pass it, I mean `int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec`. Are those two values the width and the height of the screen? 

I tried to call it in the `MyView` costructor but it gives me an error. Could you help me @Sam Rad?

Comment: Foregive me if I am so "dumb", but it's my first experience in this area... so I don't know those things very well!

Comment: @TheGreatGatsby, you don't need to call it explicitly. It is called by the system when it's going to layout the view. `h` and `w` are the variables that you would need. But of course you will have to change some part of your code. I'm freaking busy now but I will give a little more when I'm done.

Comment: @TheGreatGatsby, I have found a way to scale the image while keeping the aspect ration. I also was able to center the image on canvas. But the problem is that `FloodFill` works as of the image is positioned at `(0,0)` and not the center. If you can sort this out, it'll be finished I believe.

Comment: So this means that I can set the right dimensons of the image on the screen, but I can't use "Flood fill" algorithm?

Comment: @TheGreatGatsby, see [this](http://pastebin.com/3h7QQqk1) and try for yourself. You should change the Flood Fill code or the way you are receiving the `touch` events. In `onDraw` I left you a message in comments. Compile the app with either of the lines and see what happens.

Comment: I tried the code and it seems that myClick is shifted t-i pixels down or right, it dipends on the image I load!
For example: If I click in the point [30 px; 50 px] it modifies the point [(30 + t1) px; (50 + t2) px]. Is there a way to get the shift values and sum or substract them to the point where the user tapes?

Comment: Isn't it possible to set a `onTouchListener` to the `ImageView` and then pass the co-ordinates to the Flood Fill? I tried it but it gives me an error: _The method setOnTouchListener(View.OnTouchListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new OnTouchListener(){})_

Comment: @TheGreatGatsby, as you may have noticed, we are using an offset in `drawBitmap` method. Those offsets must explain the `t1` and `t2` values that you get. Test if this is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- Replace the main layout with a `LinearLayout` with `orientation="vertical"`
- Remove the `RelativeLayout` which wraps your `ImageView`.
- Set `layout_width` and `layout_height` to `"match_parent"` on your `ImageView`, and add `layout_weight` to value `"1"`.
- Wraps your buttons in a new `LinearLayout` with `orientation="horizontal"` with `layout_width="match_parent"` and `layout_height="wrap_content"`.

Then play with the `adjustViewBounds` and `scaleType` properties of your `ImageView` to adjust it to your need.

HTH

Comment: Thank you @tbruyelle, but I can't resolve the problem! Infact I obtain the same thing...

Comment: you ask to extend your image to all the light-grey area, my solution should work. The light-grey is the background of your first `RelativeLayout`